# Constructing an 8x8 Table with Unique Row Patterns and Consistent Prefix-Suffix Combinations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I am looking to create an 8x8 table with specific properties related to prefix and suffix combinations. Each cell in the table represents a combination of a prefix (rows) and a suffix (columns), assigned either a 0 or a 1. The table must satisfy the following conditions (the words (prefixes and suffixes) are over an alphabet of size $2$, also the prefixes and suffixes dont have to be the same, you can assume there are as few constraints as possible):

**Prefix-closed and Suffix-closed**: Each row corresponds to a prefix and each column to a suffix. The set of prefixes and suffixes should be closed; meaning, for any given prefix (or suffix), all its prefixes (or suffixes) are also present in the set. This includes the empty word.

**Unique Row Patterns**: Each row must have a unique pattern of 0s and 1s across its cells. No two rows should have the same pattern.

**Consistency**: The table should be consistent in its assignment of 0s and 1s based on prefix and suffix combinations. For example, if combining prefix "a" with suffix "b" yields 1 in one cell, then combining an empty prefix with suffix "ab" should also yield 1, maintaining logical consistency across the table.

I am struggling with formulating a method to generate such a table that adheres to these properties, especially ensuring each row has a unique pattern while maintaining the consistency requirement. How can I approach the construction of this table? Are there known algorithms or strategies that can be applied to generate the table satisfying all the given conditions?

Comment: To ensure unique row patterns, you only need to choose three columns and assign the 8 distinct 3-bit patterns to the cells in these columns. Consistency should be straightforward.